# How do I place my self-made triangle on a specific location with my ordinal scale in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have created a triangle in D3 as a data element and would like to position it on certain locations on my graph. How I can approach this correctly?

```
triangleData = [ { "x": 1,  "y": 20}, { "x": 11,   "y": 5},
              { "x": 21,  "y": 20}, { "x": 1,  "y": 20}];

lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("monotone");

triangle = svgbody.append("path")
    .attr("class", "triangleNodes")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(triangleData))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "blue");
```

If needed I have a fiddle with my current solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/c794g977/9/

I would also like to apply zoom to this triangle so the zoom function does the same as the other objects in the svg. Any suggestions to this will also be well received! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your fiddle and code contradict each other.  Are you trying to draw a triangle with `d3.svg.line()` or use `d3.symbol.type()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is with [symbol.type](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol_type).

Your fiddle almost has it but your enter selection of:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
```

isn't "specific" enough.

Try:

```
var triangle = svg.selectAll(".triangle") // <-- specific to these paths
    .data(["D", "P"]);

triangle.exit()
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();

triangle.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class','triangle') //<-- assign the class
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d) + "," + y(statusText) + ")"; 
     })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"));
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c794g977/14/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm sorry for the confusion between the fiddle code and the one posted here. The reason for this is because I tried bot creating a triangle using d3 and creating one using path! 

This works great! Thank you very much!

I just have one question. Why is there no update in this code? If I want to update the graph I have understood it that I need an enter selection to create dom elements for the amount of data and then use the update selection to specify coordinates, style etc.

Comment: @Vanquiza, sorry I missed the update on zoom, see this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c794g977/14/

Comment: Yes thank you, I fixed that myself though. It wasn't hard to figure out after seeing how you placed the triangle in the first place. I appretiate the help!